# Empty value when converting CURL to string

Tags: c++, curl

I would like to get source code of a page, I have this function to populate a string.

My header file :

```
class Explorateur {
public:
    Explorateur();
    ~Explorateur();
    std::string RecupererCodeSource(std::string pAdresse);

    static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
    {
        ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
        return size * nmemb;
    }

};
```

My class file :

```
std::string Explorateur::RecupererCodeSource(std::string pAdresse)
{
      CURL *curl;
      CURLcode res;
      std::string readBuffer;

      curl = curl_easy_init();
      if(curl)
      {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, pAdresse);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        std::cout << "curl  : " << curl << std::endl;
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        std::cout << "res  : " << res << std::endl;
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

      }
      std::cout << "Read : " << readBuffer << std::endl;
      return readBuffer;
}
```

My main :

```
int main()
{
    Explorateur explorateur;
    std::string valeur = explorateur.RecupererCodeSource("https://www.google.com/");
    return 0;
}
```

The result is not excepted, it's empty, do you have an idea why ?

```
curl  : 0x1450d60
res  : 6
Read :
```

Comment: The curl_easy_perform returned CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST (6) https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html. What content do you expect to see?

Comment: I except the Google's page source code...

Comment: Can you change `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, pAdresse);` to ` curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, pAdresse.c_str());`?

Comment: @Anonymous: why do you expect to see any content when `curl_easy_perform()` reports failure?  It is clear that it is having trouble finding Google to begin with, so it can't download anything. And the reason is because you are not passing the correct memory address for the URL string to curl, so it fails to find the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lib Curl being a C library follows an old "good" variadic argument design. That is why you code is doing completely unexpected thing while compiling fine.

Having

```
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, ...)
```

and this in your code

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, pAdresse);
```

produces the behaviour you are witnessing.

Change in you code to this

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, pAdresse.c_str());
```

or even better if you use C++ >= 11 to this

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, pAdresse.data());
```

And it is alive)).

Comment: In C++11 and later, `c_str()` and `data()` return the same thing (a pointer to a null-terminated C string), so there is no reason to switch from `c_str()` to `data()`, especially when `c_str()` in every C++ version returns exactly what curl is expecting.

Comment: IMHO `c_str` looks more ugly + `data` brings more consistency to the code with other std containers and c++17 non-const `data` )).

Comment: `c_str` better conveys that a C-style string is being used. And you wouldn't need to use a non-const `data` in this situation anyway.

Comment: I did not mean this particular snippet, I meant overall consistency of the code using std containers in any cases. `c_str` is not the best naming for what it is meant, more this names more of a flavour of some c-compatible function for some legacy/wrapping API, than a member function of a standard library of a very different programming language. In this spirit `data` is quite good alternative, even might be some other better.